# delay function for changing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I've got this code that makes a fadein and fadeout effects to black while it changes a randomly generated image:

```
var imgs = new Array("https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/1.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/2.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/3.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/4.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/5.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/6.jpg");

function changeOverlay() {
    $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 1,}, 1000);
    $('#overlay').animate({opacity: 0,}, 1000);
}

function changeBg() {
    var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
}

function changeBackgroundSmoothly() {
    $('#masthead').animate(0, changeBg);
}

setInterval(changeOverlay,2000);
setTimeout(changeBackgroundSmoothly,3000);
```

The problem is, the image only changes the first time. How can I make it on loop, like the fadein fadeout effects are?

You can have a visual idea over here: https://store.vtxfactory.org

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer without seeing a working example, but you appear to be fading in and immediately fading out `#overlay`, so they will cancel each other out.

Comment: You have the work example over at https://store.vtxfactory.org.

Comment: @SteveKess I don't know if I understand you well, do you want to stop `changeOvelay` function until the image has charged and then start again the `changeOvelay` function Or what ?

Comment: @YouneL if you see here https://store.vtxfactory.org/ the background is switching before the black fadein effect. I need to make it as follow: 1. FadeIn Black > 2. Change background-image when FadeIn Black is at 100% > 3. FadeOut Black

Comment: @YouneL So for this to take effect I need to initially add a delay of 1 second to the `changeBackgroundSmoothly` function

Answer (score 2):

If these are fixed (pre-determined) image file names then you can use standard CSS animation like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.Container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url("");
 background-position: 0% 0%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 animation: AnimText 3s linear 0s infinite alternate none;
}

@keyframes AnimText {

   0% {opacity:1; background-image: url("C:/Users/PackardBell/Pictures/Penguins.jpg");}

  50% {opacity:0.5; background-image: url("C:/Users/PackardBell/Pictures/Lighthouse.jpg");}

 100% {opacity:0; background-image: url("C:/Users/PackardBell/Pictures/Jellyfish.jpg");}
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="Container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is how you're looping in every transition.  Every transition needs to call a callback function to notify and start over again.

```js
var imgs = new Array("https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/1.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/2.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/3.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/4.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/5.jpg","https://store.vtxfactory.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/header/6.jpg");
    
function changeOverlay(cb) {
    $('#masthead').animate({opacity: 1,}, 1000, function () {
        $('#masthead').animate({opacity: 0,}, 1000, cb);
    });
}
    
function changeBg() {
    var imgUrl = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    $('#masthead').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')');
}
    
function changeBackgroundSmoothly() {
    $('#masthead').animate(0, changeBg);
}
    
function looping() {
    changeOverlay(function() {
        changeBackgroundSmoothly();
        setTimeout(looping, 500);
    });
}
    
looping();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="masthead" style='width: 500px; height: 500px'>

</div>
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Hi, thanks it's working in sync! However, now the fadein fadeout effects are white instead of black. Any tip?

Comment: The `changeOverlay` function must be addressed to the id `#overlay` instead of `#masthead`, so the menu stays viewable on the background switch. But when I change it, the image gets out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put it in a 'do while', and execute it until you press a button or something. This in combo with a timeout function provides what you need

Comment: If I use `setInterval(changeBackgroundSmoothly,2000);` instead of `setTimeout(changeBackgroundSmoothly,3000);` it loops, but the `#masthead backgroud-image` changes immediately after the start of the function.

I need a 1s delay, but I don't know how to set it up.